# How to resolve this Gradle Build my issue?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:mergeDebugResources`.

  > C:\Users\kirobin\AndroidStudioProjects\TestLocation\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0):

You should open `colors.xml` in a regular text editor. Whenever You get

> "Content is not allowed in prolog"

it's usually because I have spaces or other characters before the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` first line. Check that all your start tags have matching end tags. You probably lost some data when the power went out, so you'll have to manually edit it back in.